# fopen crashing in RHEL 5.x while doing malloc though system has lot of available memory

Tags: malloc, fopen, glibc, libc, rhel5

I have an application which was running fine for last 15 days and below functions were getting called multiple times, but it crashed today in fopen. I have pasted the bt below, can someone please advice what might have happened wrong, from backtrace it doesn't seems to be a memory corruption as all thread data and stack variables look good. Can it be related to some bug in RHEL 5.x

```
>>(gdb) bt
>>#0  0x00fe4410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
>>#1  0x0057ab10 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#2  0x0057c421 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#3  0x005b367b in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#4  0x005bc8bd in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#5  0x005be247 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#6  0x005aa8ef in __fopen_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#7  0x005aa9bc in fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#8  0x0811cbff in file_timer_expiry (p_mod_ctx=0xb07e4c8, p_timer_ctx=0x7ce78368) 
>>#9  0x08117c33 in timer_handler (timerId=0xad54aa50, p_timer_info=0x7ce78368, p_module_context=0xb07e4c8)
>>#10 0x08397b43 in ProcessTimerTable (vc=0xae6edb8, nw=0xa89fd380)
>>#11 0x0839974c in Schedule (nw=0xa89fd380, f=0x832027e <BaseUpdate>, ctxt=0x9955e98)
>>#12 0x080730a1 in DriverWhile (p_info=0x95f68c8, W=0x84a698c, policy=2 '\002')
>>#13 0x080732e1 in start_id (args=0x95f68c8)
>>#14 0x006e7912 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
>>#15 0x0062747e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
>>#16 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crash inside `malloc` implementation is (in 99.99% of cases) a result of heap corruption.

It is likely that your program has printed a message, similar to

```
glibc detected ./a.out: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000c6ed50
```

to the terminal on which it ran.

To find heap corruption, use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or (better) [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (supported by recent versions of GCC and Clang).